# SQL - Find account for which all the orders have completed

Tags: sql, oracle9i

I have been roaming in google with this for couple of hours now.

Two tables are there:

```
AccountTable 
ID | AccountID | OrderID

OrderTable
ID | OrderID | OrderStatus
```

OrderStatus can have values 1,2,3,4 with 4 being completed status.

In order table, multiple rows are added as the order status is being updated.
So for a completed order, you have will have 4 rows with 1, 2, 3 and 4 status respectively, in OrderTable.

Single account can have multiple orders.

I want to find the accounts for which all the orders have completed.

I found up to this much:

```
select * from AccountTable
INNER JOIN OrderTable
ON AccountTable.OrderID = OrderTable.OrderID
AND OrderTable.OrderStatus = 4
```

This will pick accounts for which there is atleast one order in completed status.

But this won't cover the scenario when one order is completed and the other order for the same account is not. I don't want to pick the account then.

EDIT:
I just wanted to show some data to make this clearer:

```
AccountTable
1 | Name1 | Order1
2 | Name1 | Order2
3 | Name2 | Order3
4 | Name2 | Order4
```

---

```
OrderTable
1 | Order1 | 1
2 | Order1 | 2
3 | Order1 | 3

4 | Order2 | 1
5 | Order2 | 2
6 | Order2 | 3
7 | Order2 | 4

8 | Order3 | 1
9 | Order3 | 2
10 | Order3 | 3
11 | Order3 | 4

12 | Order4 | 1
13 | Order4 | 2
14 | Order4 | 3
15 | Order4 | 4
```

I want to retrieve only Name2 and NOT Name1.

Comment: It looks to me like a single account can only have 1 order, however the same order can exist for many accounts.

Comment: nope, a single account can have many orders, and each order will have atmost 4 rows in the order table

Comment: Oracle ***9i***? Really? That has long been de-supported.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, my last 9i -> 11g migration is happening on 1st December. I _cannot wait_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your business logic cannot be corrupted, I think you want those accounts whose number of orders completed (status == 4) is the same as the number of orders initiated (status == 1):

```
  SELECT AccountID
    FROM (SELECT AccountTable.AccountID AS AccountID,
                 SUM(CASE OrderTable.OrderStatus WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS o1,
                 SUM(CASE OrderTable.OrderStatus WHEN 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS o4
            FROM AccountTable
            INNER JOIN
                 OrderTable
              ON AccountTable.OrderID = OrderTable.OrderID
        GROUP BY 1) d
   WHERE o1 = o4;
```

You can JOIN from there to get all fields from `AccountTable`.

As an aside, it seems to me that your tables are misleadingly named.  `AccountTable` is an *Account2Orders* table, and `OrderTable` is rather an *OrderStagesOrLifeCycle* table.

Comment: How many times people don't realize how important is to give db tables or app classes an appropritate name!!

Comment: hmm.. these are not the actual table names, actually they are quite long and boring, i just gave these names to make the question more clearer.. still , point taken. thank u

Answer (score 0):

No join, subselect. You also dont look for a copleted order - you look for an account not having an order that does not have a status 4 entry. I.e. an account where an order EXISTS That has NO status 4.

Check SQL Exists clause and group by for this. ou will ahve to get a query first that shows orders that have no status 4, then you can join that into the order table.

Answer (score 0):

edited - understand your data a bit better now:

```
Select
  c.AccountID
From (
  Select
    a.AccountID,
    o.OrderID,
    Max(o.OrderStatus) As OrderState
  From
    AccountTable a
      Inner Join
    OrderTable o
      On a.OrderID = o.OrderID
  Group By
    a.AccountID,
    o.OrderID
) c
Group By
  c.AccountID
Having
  Min(c.OrderState) = 4;
```

Comment: sorry, but this still gives me the account when i have one order completed and other not completed for that account.